# Manipulating RDF in Jena

Tags: semantics, rdf, sparql, jena, virtuoso

currently, I found out that I can query using model (Model) syntax in Jena in a rdf after loading the model from a file, it gives me same output if I apply a sparql query. So, I want to know that , is it a good way to that without sparql? Though I have tested it with a small rdf file. I also want to know if I use Virtuoso can i manipulate using model syntax without sparql?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You will probably find answer if you ask to http://answers.semanticweb.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question. If I can paraphrase, I think you're asking:

> Is it OK to query and manipulate RDF data using the Jena `Model` API instead of using
>   SPARQL? Does it make a difference if the back-end store is Virtuoso?

Assuming that's the right re-phrasing of the question, then the first part is definitively yes: you can manipulate RDF data through the `Model` and `OntModel` APIs. In fact, I would say that's what the majority of Jena users do, particularly for small queries or updates. I find personally that going direct to the API is more succinct up to a certain point of complexity; after that, my code is clearer and more concise if I express the query in SPARQL. Obviously circumstances will have an effect: if you're working with a mixture of local stores and remote SPARQL endpoints (for which sending a query string is your only option) then you may find the consistency of always using SPARQL makes your code clearer.

Regarding Virtuoso, I don't have any direct experience to offer. As far as I know, the Virtuoso Jena Provider fully implements the features of the `Model` API using a Virtuoso store as the storage layer. Whether the direct API or using SPARQL queries gives you a performance advantage is something you should measure by benchmark with your data and your typical query patterns.